# how to post (parameters) and get the response from Httpclient and Httppost in android

Tags: java, android, json, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want correct response from web server. The structure of my json response is like this.

```
{
    "message": "Successfully",
    "profile": {
        "name": "myname",
        "mail": "mymail",
        "sex" : sex
    }
}
```

But I always get the response as below.

```
{
    "message": "failed"
}
```

Below is my code.

```
String url ="myurlXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
json1.put("name", myname);
json1.put("mail", mymail);
json1.put("sex", sex);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post1 = new HttpPost(url);
post1.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post1.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post1.setEntity(new StringEntity(json1.toString(), "UTF-8"));

HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post1);
HttpEntity entity = httpresponse.getEntity();

InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
String result = convertStreamToString(stream);   

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
          try {
              is.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the server is returning an error then you'll need to check the server logs so see what went wrong.

Comment: We cannot tell as you did not show what the server expects  and how it handles data.

Comment: reactivemobile:thank you for quick responce,am cheking with same uri and parameters in Postmen(chrome extention) it shows right answers,

Comment: @greenapps:is there any wrong in my code,thank you for quick responce

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the code for this:

```
JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
json1.put("name", myname);
json1.put("mail", mymail);
json1.put("sex", sex);

json2.put("message", "Successfully");
json2.put("profile", json1);
HttpPost post1 = new HttpPost(url);

post1.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post1.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post1.setEntity(new StringEntity(json2.toString(), "UTF-8"));

HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post1);
HttpEntity entity = httpresponse.getEntity();
InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
String result = convertStreamToString(stream);
```

hope it helps

Comment: can you give me feedback if my answer was useful for you?

Comment: :Thank you for your reply.Right now am not used,but it is useful.Again am asking is there any corrections in my code